# Split one Row to Multiple Row Based on New line Character with Presto

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table in Presto:

[image: Table 1]

I want:

[image: Table 2]

I have used UNNEST function with split function but I am not able to split each line using '\n' or char(10)

```
SELECT Col1,split_Col2 
FROM tbl
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(Col2,'\n')) AS t (split_Col2)
```

does not work.

Even this:

```
SELECT Col1,split_Col2 
FROM tbl
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(Col2,char(10))) AS t (split_Col2)
```

does not work.

I am very new to Presto and it would be great if someone could help!

Comment: Any error log or something?

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? Please explain the problem in more details.

Comment: It does not give me rows that are split. It just displays the same results. I am not able to split it using delimiter as newline character

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to use the [`chr()` function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html):

```
SELECT Col1,split_Col2 
FROM tbl
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(Col2,chr(10))) AS t (split_Col2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to give the actual newline (enter button) instead of a escape sequence  `'\n'` or char(10)

use:

```
SELECT Col1,split_Col2  FROM tbl CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(Col2,'  
')) AS t (split_Col2)
```

This works